# How to join list items while transforming the item in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

In Ansible, how can i join list items while transforming the item?
For example, i have two variables:

```
es_hosts:
  - 192.168.100.1
  - 192.168.100.2
  - 192.168.100.3
es_port: 9200
```

How can i get the following result:

```
"http://192.168.100.1:9200,http://192.168.100.2:9200,http://192.168.100.3:9200"
```

I have tried `join` filter and `{% for %}` statement, but didn't work out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_string: "{{ ['http://']|
                       product(es_hosts)|map('join')|
                       product([es_port])|map('join', ':')|
                       join(',') }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_string
```

gives

```yaml
  my_string: http://192.168.100.1:9200,http://192.168.100.2:9200,http://192.168.100.3:9200
```